# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError :: Class present at the given path in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat6, classloader

I am currently facing with a problem where I am running a Jasper report application.

After invoking a report generation request I am facing
 `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`

for an application class e.g. `com.abcd.framework.web.servicelocator.ServiceLocator`

I verified that the class is present at the appropriate path under the `tomcat/WEB-INF/classes` folder.

I also enabled Tomcat classloader logs with

```
JAVA_OPTS = -XX:+TraceClassLoading -XX:+TraceClassUnloading
```

the relevant log:
`[Loaded com.abcd.framework.web.servicelocator.ServiceLocator from file:/C:/3.0/tomcat-6.0-Jasper/webapps/jasperserver-pro/WEB-INF/classes/com/abcd/framework/web/servicelocator/ServiceLocator.class]`

I am not able to figure out why, despite the class is successfully loaded, am getting error.

Appreciate your help

Thanks

Added Stack trace below

```
> 14:43:28,538 ERROR ManagementServiceImpl,http-30880-1:1294 - caught
> Throwable exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not
> initialize class com.abcd.framework.web.servicelocator.ServiceLocator
> com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.JSException:
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
> com.abcd.framework.web.servicelocator.ServiceLocator  at
> com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:497)
>   at
> com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.executeReportUnitRequest(EngineServiceImpl.java:1666)
>   at
> com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.domain.impl.ReportUnitRequest.execute(ReportUnitRequest.java:67)
>   at
> com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.execute(EngineServiceImpl.java:399)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
> org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
>   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
>   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>   at
> org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80)
>   at
> com.jaspersoft.ji.license.LicenseCheckAspect.runReport(LicenseCheckAspect.java:113)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
> org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
>   at
> org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
>   at
> org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)
>   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:161)
>   at
> org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
>   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
>   at $Proxy210.execute(Unknown Source)    at
> com.jaspersoft.ji.adhoc.service.AdhocEngineServiceImpl.execute(AdhocEngineServiceImpl.java:2243)
>   at
> com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.ws.axis2.ManagementServiceImpl.runReport(ManagementServiceImpl.java:1200)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
> org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
>   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
>   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>   at
> org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80)
>   at
> com.jaspersoft.ji.license.LicenseCheckAspect.executeMSCall(LicenseCheckAspect.java:118)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
> org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
>   at
> org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
>   at
> org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)
>   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>   at
> org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
>   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
>   at $Proxy267.runReport(Unknown Source)  at
> com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.ws.axis2.ManagementService.runReport(ManagementService.java:240)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
> org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
>   at
> org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
>   at
> org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
>   at
> org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
>   at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)     at
> org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)   at
> org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:453)
>   at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)    at
> org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)     at
> org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:399)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
>   at
> com.jaspersoft.ji.license.JILicenseFilter.doFilter(JILicenseFilter.java:66)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
>   at
> com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.user.service.impl.MetadataAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(MetadataAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:139)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
>   at
> com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.user.service.impl.PasswordExpirationProcessingFilter.doFilter(PasswordExpirationProcessingFilter.java:85)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
>   at
> com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.multipleTenancy.MTBasicProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(MTBasicProcessingFilter.java:180)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
>   at
> com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.user.service.impl.JIPortletAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(JIPortletAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:81)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
>   at
> com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.logging.filter.BasicLoggingFilter.doFilter(BasicLoggingFilter.java:53)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:188)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:99)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
> com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:67)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
> com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.P3PFilter.doFilter(P3PFilter.java:43)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:558)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
>   at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:859)
>   at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1555)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by:
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
> com.abcd.framework.web.servicelocator.ServiceLocator  at
> com.abcd.myproject.service.ReportProcessingService.fetchReportRecords(ReportProcessingService.java:810)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
> org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
>   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
>   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>   at
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
>   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
>   at $Proxy268.fetchReportRecordsForCTR275(Unknown Source)    at
> com.abcd.myproject.ReportDataSourceServiceImpl.setReportParameterValues(ReportDataSourceServiceImpl.java:79)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
> org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
>   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
>   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:50)
>   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
>   at $Proxy315.setReportParameterValues(Unknown Source)   at
> com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:1463)
>   at
> com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$ReportFill.runReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:874)
>   at
> com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$ReportRunnable.run(EngineServiceImpl.java:754)
>   at
> com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$SynchronousExecutor.execute(EngineServiceImpl.java:733)
>   at
> com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:488)
>   ... 115 more
```

Comment: Post the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Most of the time java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError is not the actual problem. There should be another exception before that. You should be looking for an exception which happens during the static initialization of the class in the message. Any access to this class will trigger NoClassDefFound but it means only that the class fails to initialize.

Comment: I have added Stack Trace in original Post

Comment: Actually there is no Exception before this exception.
for debugging purpose I tried adding static block & printing statement inside static block
But it never get executed

Comment: make sure you have your jasper related jars in tomcat classpath.

Comment: Are there any static fields in this class com.abcd.framework.web.servicelocator.ServiceLocator?

Comment: Are the jasper jars in your webapp, under WEB-INF/lib, or are they in Tomcat's classpath? They should be in WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: All the Jasper related JARs are present in 
tomcat/WEb-INF/lib directory

The ServiceLocator is singleton class ....so the Only static field is instance variable of ServiceLocator itself

Comment: You mean in your webapp's WEB-INF/lib? Tomcat doesn't have a WEB-INF directory.

Comment: Yes ... I am sorry ...
i meant mywebapp/WEB-INF/lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some clarifications:

1. `NoClassDefFoundError` != `ClassNotFoundException`
2. `NoClassDefFoundError` usually means that the JVM once tried to instantiate that class but failed on doing it.

So, some tips:

- Look for the first exception with that class.
- Look for some `ExceptionInInitializerError` before the `NoClassDefFoundError`
- Probably the error is in the `static` blocks of your class.

Answer (score 1):

`NoClassDefFound` indicates, that everything was okay at compile time, but not at runtime. Maybe some of your `.jars` are missing on your tomcat. You have to add them to tomcat classpath or copy them to the JRE your tomcat is running on.

here [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java) you may find some more information/explanation.

and here [Jars not copied to Tomcat's lib folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041991/jars-not-copied-to-tomcats-lib-folder) is a thread about setting up eclipse to deploy dependencies automatically.