# Eclipse don't deploy war file in Tomcat correctly

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, web-deployment

I am writing an web application and try to deploy it in tomcat with eclipse.
But everytime, if I try to start the server in eclipse I get an Error.

```
Schwerwiegend: Exception starting filter app
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4565)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5180)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

If I deploy the war file manual to tomcat it works without problems.
The war file has the necessary jars in the lib folder.

Can some give me a solution for this, please?

Comment: Are you using the tomcat-eclipse plugin?

Comment: No, I never use such a plugin. This is not my first web application. The error appears suddenly.

Comment: did u try to remove the server from eclipse and re-configure it?

Comment: Yes, I did it 5 times. But nothing. There isn't even a war file in the tomcat webapps directory, if i start it in eclipse.

Comment: The lack of a .war isn't the issue. Where is the org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter class? Does Eclipse know to deploy it?

Comment: The integrated Software in eclipse maven creates the package and deploy it in the target folder as a war file. This war file has all libraries(I checked it). But he doesn't deploy it to the tomcat webapps folder. I can deploy the war myself and start tomcat with startup.bat (works) but this is very uncomfortable :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve it with Right click on Project properties -> Deployment Assembly -> Add (button) -> Java Build Path Entries (select) -> Maven dependencies (select and click on finish)

[Jars not copied to Tomcat's lib folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041991/jars-not-copied-to-tomcats-lib-folder)